# SQL Server : fix Error 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1. Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, authentication, instance

I'm trying to connect to my local system. But the server cannot be connected and getting the below error.

> Cannot connect to HSL11594.
>
> Login failed for user 'user\user'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: Servername
> Error Number: 18456
> Severity: 14
> State: 1
> Line Number: 65536

I have read many suggestions to change the authentication mode by right clicking the instance. But I don't find any instance in my SQL Server object explorer. I tried to reinstall SQL Server which failed with error 'No instance in this computer'.

Please guide me what is happening and what needs to be fixed. If I don't login how do I expect an instance in object explorer?

Comment: For security, the underlying reason for the failed authentication is obscured to the client. Get with your DBA - there is more information in the db server's error log as to why the login failed. If *you're* the admin, you have the ability to do that yourself.

Comment: As already mentioned by Ben, look in the instance's ERRORLOG file for the correct State number associated to the login error message, then consult [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the failure cause and resolution.

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456 but it’s not going to help much if you can’t find the instance or don’t even know if SQL Server is installed where you’re looking.

Comment: I could find the instance in the configuration manager. But when i try to access through command prompt with sqlcmd it comes back with the below error.
'Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .'
Could anybody figure out from the error whether the instance exists or not.
Command used to reach the instance as below
'sqlcmd -S Server\MYSQLSERVER'

Comment: According to @BenThul's answer, I checked the error log file, and it says password is incorrect. For some reason my password was changed. so I reset it, and it works